# How to obtain a substring based on index in C

Tags: c, string, char, substring

For some background, I'm not too familiar with C, but I'm very proficient in Java.  In the current program I'm working on, I'm trying to figure out how to implement something exactly like the java method `someString.substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)` that returns a new String based on the starting and ending index of the previous one.

For the purposes of my implementation, I would only cut the first char off and return the remaining String.  Here's my implementation in java.

```
public String cut_string(String word)
{

    String temp = word.substring(1, word.length());
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: What do you need the substring for? I ask, because the C technique for substrings depends on whether you need the substring only temporarily, whether it should be modified, etc.

Comment: I will continue to manipulate the resulting string. It should do to just be able to copy it to a new location in memory

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* substring(char*, int, int);

int main() 
{
   char string[100], *pointer;
   int position, length;

   printf("Input a string\n");
   gets(string);

   printf("Enter the position and length of substring\n");
   scanf("%d%d",&position, &length);

   pointer = substring( string, position, length);

   printf("Required substring is \"%s\"\n", pointer);

   free(pointer);

   return 0;
}

/*C substring function: It returns a pointer to the substring */

char *substring(char *string, int position, int length) 
{
   char *pointer;
   int c;

   pointer = malloc(length+1);

   if (pointer == NULL)
   {
      printf("Unable to allocate memory.\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   for (c = 0 ; c < length ; c++)
   {
      *(pointer+c) = *(string+position-1);      
      string++;   
   }

   *(pointer+c) = '\0';

   return pointer;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
char* cut_string(char const* in)
{
   // Compute the length of the input string and use
   // that length to allocate memory for the string to
   // be returned.
   // strlen(in) returns the length of the string.
   // malloc(...) allocates memory.
   char* ret = malloc(strlen(in));
   if ( ret == NULL )
   {
      // If there is a problem in allocating memory
      // return NULL. We can't do anything about 
      // cutting the input string.
      return NULL;
   }

   // Copy the input string to the string to be returned.
   // Start copying from the second character. If
   // in is "This is a string", in+1 is "his is a string".
   strcpy(ret, in+1);

   // Return the resulting string.
   return ret;
}
```

In the calling function,

```
char* s = cut_string("my string");
if ( s != NULL )
{
   // Use s

   // Make sure to free the memory returned by cut_string.
   free(s);
}
```

Comment: He's a Java boy, make sure to mention he has to free that pointer when he is done with it :)